# elastic search on qbox is not accesible through nutch

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I have a qbox instance for elastic search (more details about qbox elasticsearch can be found at http://qbox.io/) with a custom tcp port.
When I try to access the instance through nutch for indexing I get following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:278)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.bulk(AbstractClient.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.bulk(TransportClient.java:364)
    at org.2016-06-30 15:39:14,320 WARN  mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Output path is null in cleanup
2016-06-30 15:39:14,320 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local561208907_0001
java.lang.Exception: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:278)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClient.execute(InternalTransportClient.java:106)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.bulk(AbstractClient.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.bulk(TransportClient.java:364)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestBuilder.doExecute(BulkRequestBuilder.java:164)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.elastic.ElasticIndexWriter.commit(ElasticIndexWriter.java:208)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.elastic.ElasticIndexWriter.close(ElasticIndexWriter.java:226)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTaselasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestBuilder.doExecute(BulkRequestBuilder.java:164)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.elastic.ElasticIndexWriter.commit(ElasticIndexWriter.java:208)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexwriter.elastic.ElasticIndexWriter.close(ElasticIndexWriter.java:226)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexWriters.close(IndexWriters.java:114)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
k.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error when either cluster host/port or cluster name does not match on client and server.

In your `$NUTCH_ROOT/runtime/local/conf/nutch-site.xml` please make sure you have correctly configured the host, port and cluster name that matches the cluster name on qbox.io -

```
<property>
  <name>elastic.host</name>
  <value></value>
  <description>The hostname to send documents to using TransportClient. Either host
  and port must be defined or cluster.</description>
</property>

<property> 
  <name>elastic.port</name>
  <value>9300</value>
  <description>The port to connect to using TransportClient.</description>
</property>

<property> 
  <name>elastic.cluster</name>
  <value></value>
  <description>The cluster name to discover. Either host and port must be defined
  or cluster.</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @pranav :) . I think I found out the issue: Earlier I used nutch version 2.3 with elasticsearch version 2.3.3 which now I changed to 1.7.1 and it worked fine.

Comment: Which version you changed ? Version of elastic or nutch ?

Comment: has to be elasticsearch version.. 2.3.3 and 1.7.1 are both (relatively) recent elasticsearch versions in 1.x and 2.x release streams

Comment: @Sachin I changed elasticsearch version 2.3.3 to 1.7.1

Comment: Hey I got the solution for this. You don't need to downgrade ES. Instead you build from source(master branch) https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/ where you can customize version of ES plugin before you build. Cheers :)

Comment: The link https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/ is not working :(